# Passing authentication to a different domain Iframe

Tags: vue.js, iframe, local-storage, axios

I have to different apps that requires the exact same autentication and i am trying to pass my authentication information from localStorage from one app to another without having the user login twice. I am trying to use the following guide btu i am not sure on how to proceed:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains-eb07581e9384

This is the information i want to pass forward to my Iframe:

```
token: 1234567890abcdef
user: someUserName
expires: 987654321
```

My component looks like the following:

```
<template>
    <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
      <v-content>
    <div>
      <ToolBar/>
    </div>
      <vue-friendly-iframe id="frame" name="frame" src="http://localhost:8081"></vue-friendly-iframe>
    </v-container>

</template>

<script>

import ToolBar from '@/components/component/ToolBar'

  const domains = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://localhost:8081"
  ]

  export default {

    name: 'Dashboard',

      components: {
        ToolBar
    },

    data () {
      return {
        //
      }
    },

  }
</script>
```

Not really sure on how to proceed here

Comment: Do you control both apps? If so, the easiest way is to use a proxy (nginx, etc.) to additionally serve the framed app via a route under the main domain. I do exactly this in my app for the same purpose and it makes everything a lot easier.

Comment: Yes i do. I never used nginx and i am new to veu in general, they are both running on local host, on ports 8080 and 8081 respectively. How would i go about this codewise?

Comment: @DavidWeldon I have used nginx to serve the framed app via a route under the main domain, but how does the framed app get authentication data (username/password, etc), can you elaborate on that? Thanks.

Comment: @Qiulang Because the two use the same domain name, they should have access to the same local storage.

Comment: So it is not because using a reverse proxy makes this work but because they are in the same domain and can share cookie/local storage in the browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> TLDR: There is really no perfect solution for this.

Having said this, there are a couple of approaches you can take.

#### Using Reverse Proxy

As @David suggested, use a reverse proxy like Nginx or HAPorxy to serve both the applications from the same domain - `protocol://host:port`. All three things should be equal.

#### Using cookies instead of LocalStorage

If you use cookies instead of `LocalStorage`, then host ports do not participate in determining site policy. So two application running on the same host but the different port will share cookie without any extra work. To protect the cookie, use an HTTP-only cookie, same-site cookie.

#### Using URL to share - IFrame only

If you are using iFrame, then you can use URL to share the token. When the outer window is loading the iFrame, send this information via hash like `http://localhost:8081/somepage#token=1234`

Using hash will allow the page to send data to an inner page without being sent over the wire.

#### Using window.postMessage - IFrame only

Using [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), you can simply pass the required data to the inner window/iFrame. As long as you control both the endpoints, you can easily do cross-domain message sending.

In the end, it really depends on your security requirements, ease-of-maintenance, etc.

Comment: I used the last method of postMessage with iframes. I was able to log into the other page page passing the authentication trough post message, however it is not actually saving my local storage information, but so far this helped. thanks bud.

Comment: It seems insecure to include the token in the URL like this. Is this safe?

Comment: If you use the `hash` fragment, then the token never leaves the browser and thus always safe.

Comment: @HarshalPatil for the 1st method, using a reverse proxy to server 2 apps, but how does that give the inner iFrame the authentication data? Can you further elaborate on that? Thanks

Comment: @Qiulang When you use the reverse proxy, it means you serve two apps on same domain. The way to differentiate between two apps is the `/path/to/app` fragment. Thus, the moment you login on any of the app, the cookies will be shared automatically since you are dealing with a same domain. Load the app in `<iframe />` or in a different tab of the same browser, the authentication cookie would always be sent and available.

Comment: Yes, I know cookies are shared on the same domain. I just don't understand why using a reverse proxy can be a standalone approach to share the login data between two app.